How to filter out ANSI escapes such as colors from captured command (in other words: how to de-colorize command output)?
I want to run grep on a remote host, so I initially did this:
ssh box grep needle haystack.txt

But I wanted pretty colors, so I changed it to this:
ssh -t box grep --color needle haystack.txt

This mostly worked, until I wanted to save the output to a file, so then I did this
ssh -t box grep --color needle haystack.txt | tee record.txt

But now record.txt contains the escape codes for colored output, which I do not want.  How can I get plain text in my "transcript"?

Have you considered omitting the --color option when you plan to redirect the output to a file?  It seems a bit counterproductive to go out of your way to ask for output in a form that you don't want.

Remove --color from the initial grep, and apply it to a local grep just before reaching STDOUT: ssh -t box grep needle haystack.txt | tee record.txt | grep --color needle

@ John B... the output is going to a file and also to terminal: I want to keep the terminal output colored ... @ pmf ... thank you I feel like an idiot ... this will require refactoring my script a bit but it's probably better than trying to parse ANSI escape sequence to remove the ones I don't want

@ pmf ... actually on second thought this doesn't quite do what I want ... I want record.txt to ONLY have lines that match "needle" ... I just don't want those lines to be colored ... further, the real script is more complicated in ways that make it much more convenient to run grep on the server (e.g., I don't want to pipe a huge file through the SSH connection just to have the whole thing filtered out).

@MarkVY grep is still executed on the server, just without --color, thus record.txt will only contain matching lines. Maybe I should have written …to another local grep…

Oh, sorry, I misread what you wrote... clever!  So the idea is that the local grep does no real filtering, it ONLY does coloring ... this is technically not QUITE equivalent since the remote one may have info the local one doesn't have... like if I do grep -n needle haystack1 haystack2 then the remote grep is able to use three distinct colors for line numbers and file names and matches, whereas the local one can only highlight matches... but maybe that's good enough here, and saves the trouble of parsing ANSI escapes.  But as the superuser post above shows, parsing escapes is not so bad.

Google "remove ansi escape sequences from file" and you'll find a number of solutions.

For the removal approach, read about CSI sequences to know what to match: For Control Sequence Introducer, or CSI, commands, the ESC [ (written as \e[ or \033[ in several programming languages) is followed by any number (including none) of "parameter bytes" in the range 0x30–0x3F (ASCII 0–9:;<=>?), then by any number of "intermediate bytes" in the range 0x20–0x2F (ASCII space and !"#$%&'()*+,-./), then finally by a single "final byte" in the range 0x40–0x7E (ASCII @A–Z[\]^_`a–z{|}~).

@ pmf thanks! ... @ Thomas ... I have already linked to the question I feel that this is most similar to, please see my first comment

@ whoever closed the question as a duplicate: fine with me, but please link to the answer on superuser which actually answers the question, not the irrelevant telnet question which DOES NOT
